# Implementation of a chat service using Restlet api

Tags: restlet, chatroom

First off I'm not too familiar with restlets , just starting out. I wanted to implement a broadcast chatroom where a client sending a message would have the message broadcast to all other clients.

```
   My attempt was to use a resource on the server side where the client would send the message(as a String) using POST. The other clients would constantly have to poll this resource to receive the message. I know this method must be horribly ineffective. 

   I was wondering if there was a better method where a change on the server side(in this case the sending of the string message) would result in the server alerting the clients of this update.
```

Answer (score 0):

Some things will come in version 2.1 with the new nio connector. Within web page, you might consider using technologies like Comet or HTML5 web sockets.

See the specification page from the developer wiki of Restlet: http://wiki.restlet.org/developers/172-restlet/g3/354-restlet.html

Thierry